# How to overcome maya?

Tags: maya

[Refer what is Maya here](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/2053/what-is-maya-and-why-is-it-there) It has acquired almost everyone in this world. Consider me as one of the worst cases. I am willing to control "Maya" and attain at-least consciousness. I know attaining moksha may take several seconds/minutes/hours/years etc.,  at-least I need to control it.

What are all the ways to control Maya and attain consciousness. I am willing to pray god regularly but due to Maya I cannot full fill my prayers, is there any mantra you would recommend? are there any practices?

Comment: @K.C.Polai, Attaining moksha is overcoming Maya (to my knowledge), I  mentioned in my question it is a difficult one. I just need to control it atleast. Thank you

Comment: Possible duplicate or Strongly related of [Why does the soul fall prey to maya, when it resides in the body?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/6625/why-does-the-soul-fall-prey-to-maya-when-it-resides-in-the-body)

Comment: When Krishna shows Brahmana in mouth to his mother then he also shows game of world. Means, He shows his maya is making people cry and same maya also making people smile also. Time to time maya makes every person cry/laugh or happy/sad. And same maya standing in front of Vishnu with fear/scared. Like this Krishna shown whole game of world to his mother. Maya plays with everyone but same maya scared of Vishnu. Even Vishnu said maya don't has guts to play with his devotees. So only way to get rid of maya is true devotion and self realization.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> "satsangatve nissangatvam 
>  
>    nissangatve nirmOhatvam 
>    nirmOhatve nizcala tatvam 
>    nizcala tatve jIvanmuktiH"
>
> -Sankaracharya in bhaja govindam.

The second line in the above verse is what you are looking for. Sankara says release from attachment progresses one towards overcoming maya and such non-attachment is achieved through continuous company of the pious.

Translation of the whole sloka is given in the linked answer.

https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/7697/1195

Answer (score 7):

> I am willing to pray god regularly but due to Maya I cannot full fill
>   my prayers

I can not understand why is it so. We all (everyone that is) live within the clutches of MAyA but still we can offer prayers and get them fulfilled (at least some or many among us can). Then why can't you?

I think you need to define exactly what you mean by MAyA in this question. Because MAyA is a scriptural term, and so if you do not define it, the answers will be based on the scriptural usages of the term.

Now, coming to MAyA, it is too powerful. Its like an weapon (the PashA) that ParAshakti ( the power of Parabrahman) holds in her hands.

It is so powerful that everyone including Rishis, Gods and even the Trinities get deluded by it. Then who are we to overcome it?

The definition of MahAmAyA is as follows:

> Mahati chAsau mAyA cheti mahAmAyA |
>  BrahmA vishnu shivAdinAm
>   mohajanakatvAt mahAmAyA ||
>
> .......
>
> The MAyA that is great is called MAhAmAyA. Since it deludes even the
>   Trinities- Brahma-Vishnu-Shiva, it has been so called.

Another definition of MAyA:

> Saiva mAyA prakritiryA sammohati shankaram |
>  Harim tathA
>   virinchincha tathaivAnyAmshcha nirjjarAn ||
>
> ............
>
> The Prakriti, which deludes Brahma, Vishnu and Shankara and other Gods,
>   is known as MAyA.
>
> **YAmala Tantram.**

So, if it is so powerful that even the Trinities are affected by it, how can we ordinary mortals overcome it?

But, there is a way. It seems very easy when we simply hear it but how much difficult it is to practically achieve it is for them to say who tried their hands at it.

> Dve pade vandhamokshAya mameti nirmameti cha |
>  **Mameti vAdyate
>   janturna nirmameti vimuchyate ||**
>
> ..............
>
> Mama (Mine) and Nir-Mama (Not Mine)- These two words are respectively
>   the indicators of Bandhana (bondage due to illusion) and Moksha
>   (liberation from bondage). The thought "Mine" binds the Jiva, but the
>   thought "Not-Mine" liberates it.
>
> **KulArnava Tantram 1.112**

So, when you think " I am the owner", " I am the one who enjoys/suffers", "My wealth", "My son", "My wife", "My friends"  etc you are still under the clutches of MAyA. And, when you are able to do exactly the opposite of the above then you are liberated. In other words, when you are devoid of the **I-Ahamakara** you are said to have successfully overcome what you call MAYA.

Comment: Thank you for the most perfect answer. In simple English for understanding indeed. Much appreciated!

Answer (score 4):

- Maya is not the problem, Ignorance or wrong identification is the problem.
- There are neither any ways to control Maya nor any need.
- You want to control MAyA or `attain at-least consciousness.` I repeat, `at-least` , Can you tell how it is at least when it is everything.
- `I want to attain consciousness` is like saying of waves in water that they want to become water. See, if waves lose their identification of being wave, they are already water. This is the way... Liberation is never of the person, it is from the person.

There are broadly three techniques for liberation in Kashmiri Shaivism namely- ShAmbhavopAye, ShAktopAye & AnavoppAye. Personally, I would suggest you to start from AnavopAye but herein I am summarizing ShAmbhavopAye technique just to initially theorize the fact that what we are looking for is already we are as Kabir Das said - "I cry because I see fishes are thirsty."

> In this highest state of supreme God consciousness [anuttara] there is no need of spiritual progress, no contemplation, no art of expression, no investigation, no meditation, no concentration, no recitation, exertion or practice. Tell me then, what is the supreme and well-ascertained truth? Listen indeed to this! Neither abandon nor accept anything, enjoy everything, remain as you are! A.A-1 
>   In reality there is no such thing as birth and death, so how can the question arise of bondage for living beings? There never was any such bondage for the one who is entirely free, and therefore, to struggle for liberation is useless and nothing more than delusion–like a dark shadow mistaken for a demon, or a rope seen as a snake. It is all based on deceitful perception which has no substance. Neither abandon nor accept anything, remain as you are, well established in your own Self. A.A-2. 
>   In the oneness of that supreme state of anuttara what talk can there be, and what differentiated path of adorer, adored and adoration? To whom and by what means could a progression function; or what could constitute the succession of penetrating into the Self? Wonder of wonders! Though it appears differentiated this illusion is no other than consciousness–one without a second. Everything is nothing but the pure essence of your own Self-experience, so why worry in vain! A.A-3

Comment: could you please explain your answer in English rather more sanskrit terms, do you mean that I can't do anything about Maya? Just forget about Maya and do what I do?

Comment: I mean mAyA is Shiva's power, mAyA is the power by which non duality is distorted. Simply, you don't need to think about mAyA for liberation, just choose any Anavopaye technique/practice.  And what Sanskrit terms you can't understand?

Answer (score 2):

In a very simple language " START WORSHIPING  LORD KRISHNA " . It will take years to achieve.  At every stage your soul will guide you . You just follow your soul. You will have to give up lust , anger, jealousy  etc. And try to become Satvik. No one in this world will guide you. It is   Parmatma situated within you. Start with mantra "Hare Krishna hare Krishna " gradually  you will realise it within yourself .

Comment: Hello! please register and continue contributing. Visit [answer] page and take a [tour] of our site.

Answer (score 0):

In order to make this understandable from the perspective of a society-influenced modern person, which I happened to be one of them, first calm your mind and tell yourself that you are not the body, not the mind but the supreme conscience. Don't attach yourself to your body at the same time take care of it as it is a gift blessed to us by the Lord to carry out our duties. Don't worry how you look, how others judge you or what will happen in the future. Completely surrender yourself to God. Understand that God has given you this birth and all the good stuff, God knows what is good and what is not good for you. Whatever happens in your life, trust that God is doing it for your good. Reduce or stop attachment with friends. Talk only what is needed, stop all the gossip/fun, once you get to a supreme form of purity you can speak well with others and Maya won't influence you that time. You will feel blissful all the time. Trust your conscience and do what it tells you to do.

Fix your mind on a physical form (an avatar), and fall in love. In my case, it was sathya Sai baba. There are many YouTube videos that showed his miracles. There will be different ways God will test you if you are faithful. Once you believe, you will start falling in love with the nature of God through his service to the mankind. You will start realizing how amazing God is. You may be able to realize the instances in your life when God saved you. That will make you fall in love with the Lord, you would want nothing but the Lord's sweet name and form. That is how I overcame Maya.

Comment: Welcome to Hinduism.SE. Please add some sources to back your answer.

Comment: Sorry, I don't have a link. Please search in YouTube - Sathya Sai Divine Discourses, or Sathya Sai miracles. You can also visit Sathya Sai Service organization. http://www.sathyasai.org/sathya-sai/his-words People who knew, they don't talk or market about his message. It happens through word of mouth. I wanted to give a chance for others here similar to how God gave me a chance.