# Maya and Lord Shiva

Tags: scripture, shiva, krishna, durga, maya

[From the lecture of HG Amogh Lila Prabhu](https://youtu.be/0n13r73pwP8)

2:49-3:03

Quoting HG:

> This tatva(Lord Shiva’s) is unaffected by Maya;it is neither beyond(transcending) Maya,neither is it polluted by Maya,it is pure.

Mother Durga is popularly called Mahamaya,and Lord Shiva is her husband.

This said,can it be believed that Lord Shiva is beyond/transcending Maya,as Mother Durga calls Lord Shiva
**“swami”** (I understand this as subservience,not due to inability of Mother,but as the Lord is Her husband?),and *therefore beyond and more powerful than the Mother’s/Maya’s potency,contrary to what HG said?*

Comment: मायां तु प्रकृतिं विद्यान्मायिनं च महेश्वरम् । तस्यवयवभूतैस्तु व्याप्तं सर्वमिदं जगत् ॥ 
Know, then, that Prakriti is Maya and Maheswara is the wielder of the Maya. The whole universe is filled with objects which are parts of His being. (Sve. Upanishad 4.10)

Comment: @Tezz Maheshwari refers to Lord Shiva only right?As some epiteths are used interchangingly for both Lord Shiva and Lord Vishnu.

Comment: Maheswari refers to Goddess (/consort or Shakti of Maheswara). eg. in Saptashati Devi Maheswari comes out of Lord Shiva and she rides bull, holds trident, has three eyes etc... Maheswara generally refers to Lord Shiva. But it is also used to describe other Gods in the sense of Maha Ishwara (The Great Lord).

Comment: @Tezz;sorry ,my bad.I guess autocorrect got me.Thanks!

Comment: प्रकृतिः पुरुषश्चोभे मम रूपे दुरत्यये। अनुप्रविश्य द्वितयं क्षोभयाम्यहमिच्छया॥ - Devi is also a form of Brahman only. And Brahman says- Prakriti (insentient or jada) and Purusha (sentient or chetana) are my two forms uncrossable. Present in both they’re activated by him. That is to say Brahman is lord of both jada chetana. Devi is not Prakriti but Brahman herself (like Shiva) as I have linked in one question of yours. Swami is because husband is called Pati correspondingly wife is also called Patni (Swamini) though they don’t show that in TV serials and portray as one above the other.

Comment: Sorry I linked it in some other question. Here it is: https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/46403/understanding-maya-or-prakriti-as-the-supreme-goddess-is-she-only-insentient-an

Comment: @Archit ,is this your reply to Tezz?

Comment: No this is my reply to you.

Comment: @Archit Does Lord Shiva and Devi act in their independent potency?

Comment: Didn’t understand exactly what you asked. Anyway I don’t have proper knowledge if you mean something else. But I’ll try to reply. See this answer which shows Devi as Brahman and Maya being subservient to her. Actually as I said above Maya or Prakriti and Purusha both are forms if Devi only. See this answer https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/24445/20129