# What is the difference between Maya, Mahamaya and Yogamaya?

Tags: puranas, tantra, maya

What is the difference between Maya, Mahamaya and Yogamaya according to our holy scriptures?

Comment: curious to know the answer

Comment: In the following answer definitions of maya and mahamaya are given from the Tantras: https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/21420

Comment: @Rickross thanks so much

Answer (score 2):

Maya is a general word used for everything manifested aka Jada(unconscious matter)

As per Devi Bhagwatam, Mahamaya is the name of Shodashi or [Tripura Sundari](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tripura_Sundari)
who governs the Maya(world and nature)

> **She is three-fold, furthermore, because she expresses herself in
>   Brahma, Visnu, and Siva in her roles as creator, maintainer, and
>   destroyer of the universe.** She is threefold also because she
>   represents the subject (maul), instrument (mina), and object (meya) of
>   all things. Here again, she is identified with reality expressed in
>   terms of speech, which involves a speaker, what is said, and objects
>   to which the words refer.[12]
>
> Tripura Sundari is also known by names as Ṣoḍaśī ("She who is the
>   sixteenth"[13]), Lalitā, Kāmeśvarī, Śrīvidyā and Raj Rajeshwari.[2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yogmaya_Temple)
>   The Shodashi Tantra refers to Shodashi as the "Beauty of the Three
>   Cities," or Tripurasundari.
>
> **She is Tripura because she is beyond the three Gunas.** She dwells in
>   the three worlds of manas, buddhi, and chitta. She is Trayi, the
>   unified combination of the three gods Brahma, Vishnu, and Shiva. She
>   is also known as Lalita (the graceful one) and Kameshwari (the desire
>   principle of the Supreme).
>
> The Vamakeshvara tantra says that Tripura-sundari dwells on the peaks
>   of the Himalayas; is worshiped by sages and heavenly nymphs; has a
>   body like pure crystal; wears a tiger skin, a snake as a garland
>   around her neck, and her hair tied in a jata; holds a trident and
>   drum; is decorated with jewels, flowers, and ashes; and has a large
>   bull as a vehicle.
>
> The Saundaryalahari and the Tantrasara describe her in detail from her
>   hair to her feet. The Tantrasara dhyna mantra says that she is
>   illuminated by the jewels of the crowns of Brahma and Vishnu, which
>   fell at her feet when they bowed down to worship her.

Yogmaya is the specific name given to sister of Lord Vishnu/Krishna. There is 
[temple](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yogmaya_Temple) dedicated to her, which clearly describes her to be Goddess Durga only.

> It is believed that the main idol in the temple was that of Yogamaya,
>   an incarnation of Durga, born as the sister of Krishna. Kansa, cousin
>   of Devaki (mother of Krishna) and uncle of Yogamaya and Kansa
>   attempted to kill Yogamaya on Krishna Janmastami day when Krishna was
>   born. But Yogamaya, who was cleverly substituted for Krishna, vanished
>   after predicting Kansa's death at the hands of her brother Krishna

In conclusion, same deity is known with different names.**Mahamaya is the name used by Shaktas when Devi is seen as Brahman/God** while **Yogmaya(sister of Vishnu) is the name used by Vaishnavas** when Vishnu is seen as Brahman/God while **Parvati/Kaali is the name used by Shaivas** when Shiva is seen as Brahman.

Comment: very interesting, thank you!