# When Brahaman is formless how can we have description of this aspect in Vedas through Abhetha, Betha and kadaka sruthis?

Tags: vedanta, brahman

Here we are saying Brahman is formless. But in Vedas some truth is saying there is only one, in some it is saying it is having divine form, in some say soul and supreme soul are always different and we can not attain supreme soul stage anytime through Mukti or ultimate liberation and in Vedas it is explained by non dual, qualified dual, dual truths.How is it this to be considered as a proper explanation when spoken in three different voices in Vedas itself.

Comment: Different aspirants have different understandings and views. The Vedas express these different aspects of the Godhead so that different people can find their way to the Godhead. All are correct and at the same time none are correct as Brahman is avangmanasogocharam - that which is incapable of being grasped by word or mind. It does not matter what you believe or think the Godhead is, what matters is being and becoming. Realize God - then He will explain directly to you what He is and what He is not.

Comment: Good question. Imagine the ocean and wave analogy. The ocean consists of waves. The waves are different from each other. Some waves are big and some waves are small. This the Dvaita analogy. the waves are jivas. All jivas are different from each other and from God. Here God can be considered as the Tidal Wave. He is all powerful and all loving. However all waves are part of the Ocean. The ocean is the whole. The waves are its parts. The waves depend on the ocean, they cannot exist without the Ocean. The Ocean is omnipresent in all the waves. This is Vishishtadvaita analogy.

Comment: However the waves and the ocean, they all share the same essence. What is that essence? They are all basically 'water'. This water is the true identity of both the ocean and the waves. This water is by itself, colorless, odorless and tasteless. Due to the salt (maya) in it, it contains a specific taste. Due to the reflection of the sky, it appears blue. This is the Advaita analogy. All of creation is actually 'Brahman' in their true identity. Brahman Himself is attributeless, however on account of Maya, takes up attributes.

Comment: Which of this is true? All of it, isn't it? Similarly non-dual, qualified dual and dual truths are all accurate descriptions of Brahman, however they are not complete on their own. Depending on your perspective, a different side of the story appears to be visible. That's it. If you're a Bhakta, you would prefer Vishishtadvaita or Achinthyabhedabheda. If you're a Jnani, you would prefer Advaita.]

Comment: where is it said "we can not attain supreme soul stage anytime through Mukti or ultimate liberation" in Vedas?

Comment: Dualism states that even if we attain Mukti also, Paramatma and Jiva ATMA  will be in separate identity only. They will not merge.(Madhwa Philosophy)

Comment: Can you provide references from where you came accross these statements in vedas?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why isn't there one Absolute Reality?](http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/8876/why-isnt-there-one-absolute-reality)

Comment: What fabulous analogies @Sai

Comment: @Dr.VineetAggarwal Thank you, none of the above are my own creation. It is simply the parroting of the teachings of various realized souls.