# Is Hinduism one continuous stream of thought over time?

Tags: vedanta

The Vedas, Upanishads, Ithihasas and Puranas were authored over a period of around 2000 years with thousands of people being the authors. This is what modern historians have concluded and though one might dispute the dates given by them it is extremely hard to argue even from traditional beliefs that they were authored at a single time or by a single person. On the other hand, most of the great philosophers proceed on the assumption that all these texts espouse one coherent and consistent philosophy. Adi Shankara thus has written many commentaries on the Upanishads and Bhagavad Gita interpreting the texts to fit with Advaita. Similarly for Ramanuja and Madhva. However, what argument can be given to say that all these manifold texts have a single coherent viewpoint? Have the great acharayas given any argument or do they merely take it as an assumption?

Comment: If you just put all texts and make a juice of it, only one thing you will get as a result = purify the mind and reach your natural state of Atman!

Comment: Related: [Why isn't there one Absolute Reality?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/8876/277)

Comment: The literature like vedas are called apoursheya, meaning they are not authored by anyone but have existed since the beginning of time. This knowledge predates recorded history; it used to exist even before writing was invented and during those times it was transmitted by word of mouth from guru to student and in this manner it was transmitted through disciplic succession until it has now reached us.

Comment: Today, a lot of the vedic knowledge that used to exist is lost, what we know as the vedas today is just a fraction of the complete vedas. Thus the sum total of all texts may not be present and what we have available with us may not present a complete or sometimes even consistent picture. Thus we rely on the acharyas who are experts who have studied these texts thoroughly, applied their mind and come up with a consistent picture.

Comment: The purpose is to elevate everyone to highest stage of spiritual consciousness. Depending on the level of followers, instructions vary and the process prescribed varies. But ultimate aim is to elevate everyone from their respective levels. In that sense, there is singular purpose. Externally there is a lot of diversity and apparent contradictions.