# How does Vedanta (Uttara Mimamsa) school prove their Astikya (Existence of God) using Shabda pramana?

Tags: vedas, vedanta, advaita, vishishtadvaita, dvaita

How does Vedanta(Uttara Mimamsa) school of Indian philosophy prove their Astikya (Theism) using Shabda(or Agama) pramana, and also how is Shabda pramana established as a valid pramana.

It would be great if this question received answer from all                     Tri-mathasthas's (Advaita, Vishishtadvaita, Dvaita schools of Vedanta) point of view. You can answer either from any one of the three schools or you can answer from multiple schools.

This question is follow up question of [this question](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/21975/how-do-different-astika-schools-prove-the-existence-of-god?noredirect=1&lq=1), where the arguments of Vedanta school was summarized.

*It would be in the best of interest of all if the answer is **elaborate enough to make the point as to how Vedas are established as Authoritative pramana** and other concerning topics.*

Comment: Closely related: [How do different Vedantic philosophies prove the existence of the soul?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/22016/277)

Comment: Excellent quesrion! I also asked a similar question and would like to know a definitive answer. https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/29810/is-hinduism-one-continuous-stream-of-thought-over-time

Comment: @Pandya your question can be regarded as subset of this question, as this covers god and soul and how Vedas are established as authoritative pramana.

Comment: Btw, you're asking two questions. For your second question "how is Shabda pramana established as a valid pramana", visit : [What is the validity of Authoritativeness of vedas?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/14755/277)

Comment: Yes, I am asking one main question, which can split into relevant sub questions, which are very important, to give the fullness of the picture.         
This can be the goto link for all the "Online-Vedantins" to know and show how Vedas can be considered as Shabda pramana, and also the validity of Shabda pramana.

Comment: You have one disease and for that, you went to many doctors but you are still struggling with this critical disease and it is growing. One wise man insisted you go to another good doctor and you somehow agreed to this - new doctor suggested some activities to follow in an exact way and gave medicine to follow for few days, you followed those activities in the instructed way and you got cured of your long-running disease. Now, what will be your thought on that doctor? and that wise man? Personally, I will definitely promote the doctor in my circle and will be very thankful to both of them. 1/3

Comment: And luckily that same great feedback you see in Google Maps :) about that doctor or in your circle. This is what we (at least in my near by circle) sees - the behaviour of people with such doctor and the wise man. 2/3

Comment: Now, back to your questions, "how is Shabda pramana established as a valid pramana." - In above example, We (Consider it always in my near circle) had some disease and went to doctor to get it cured - and once it is cured, we agree that the doctor is great. And how we came to know about him is through sabda pramana (because the wise man told us) - and how did we make it valid pramana - through direct experience. 3/3

Comment: So who is the wise man? Wise men are those who received these mantras (they are also called Mantra-Dhrasta) - They were Rishis. They received this and like you they had doubt, they focused on those mantras / recited multiple times to get meaning out of it and somehow then have cured one of their disease (unknowingly). As they have experienced this directly, they have started trusting this and after that whatever mantra they have received, they just memorized it and pass it.

Comment: @LoveSharma  You have again missed the rigorous nature of my question. The situation is like when you have a disease and some body close to you have given good feed back and many people have given good feedback about a doctor. But this suggests it is wise for you to follow it. But it does not prove 100% about the doctor you are endorsing.

Comment: @LoveSharma I agree that it is wise and best decision to follow Vedas. What I do not agree is that you cannot establish Vedas as poorna pramana using shabda and anumana itself. Or in other words you cannot logically convince me that Vedas 100% right, you can convince me this point of time it is best to follow Vedas, of which I am already convinced. Do you get it?

Comment: I get it but seems you missed the gist in it. I haven't said Vedas are 100% right or wrong. In my comments, I haven't used the word "Vedas". I was answering your 1 of the question which I just copy pasted. Now, to your connected question "Are Vedas valid pramanas?"  I would let you decide the percentage you feel. Because it is ONLY YOU who can decide the doctor (in this case, it is Vedas) is authenticated or not, not the one who gave the answers below - those are just there perspective. 1/3

Comment: Some may give 1 star to the doctor and say he is unable to cure their diseases, it could be either (1) the patient is not following the instructions or (2) miss-interpretation of instructions or (3) you can also think that doctor gave wrong instructions, all reasons are valid. What distinguishes 1st-2nd and 3rd is willful shraddha or belief, nothing else. 2/3

Comment: As the mantra received by Rishi's are profound and loaded which no one can get/think of using their 5 senses and when they followed - It just worked! That's why Vedas are considered as Sruti, who's sruti? Ishvara's! So it is apaurushya! With today's mindset your questions is invalid - because sabda pramana is subjective and valid pramana is objective i.e., Sabda Pramana != Valid Pramana! But with Shraddha Only - Sabda Pramana == Valid Pramana! 3/3

Comment: Do you trust the newspaper or news channel? And how do you verify it? :)

Comment: You are making an argument from faith. If you bring faith there was no reason for all this tarka and debate. It could be something like Christianity, just pure faith. And moreover just because I have Shraddha in something will not make it true. I can have Shraddha on some doctor but then he could be a fraud.

Comment: @LoveSharma you are again missing the question. Its not me but it is the main acharyas of the three schools who claim (as I know) that Vedas can be established Shabda pramana. And if we strip all the beating around the bush in your comments, you are just asking me to take it in good faith, which is totally not the point of Uttara Mimamsa.

Comment: I told in simple words but you are trying to find arguable point. That's ok, now let's turn the table. Why did you asked this question here? And why do you think that you will get answer here? And in your answer do not use word "faith" or "hope". Try to be logical so I know how much detail I need to provide in which you can understand.

Comment: @LoveSharma sure, but I cannot do this in comment section, I will edit the question and will tell precisely what are the reasons for me asking this question and also start a bounty on it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/86203/discussion-between-love-sharma-and-chakrapani-n-rao).

Answer (score 1):

All three schools accept the Gita, the Upanishads, and the Brahma Sutras as the three scriptures of all schools. Brahman cannot be 'proved' through reasoning or the sensual world. Brahma Sutras 1.1.2 - 1.1.4 addresses this very question. Brahma Sutras 1.1.2 - 1.1.4 read (Brahma Sutras, Swami Vireswarananda translator, available here - https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/brahma-sutras):

> 2. (Brahman is that omniscient, omnipotent cause) from which proceed the origin etc., (i.e. sustenance and dissolution) of this (world).
> 3. The scriptures (alone) being the means of right knowledge (with regard to Brahman, the proposition laid in Sutra 2 becomes collaborated).
> 4. But that (Brahman is to be known only from the scriptures and not independently by any other means is established) because It is the main purport (of all Vedanta texts).

The proof of God is *sruti* (vedas). If you do not accept the assertion of *sruti*, you are not a Vedantist, no matter what your school.

Comment: You have missed the point of the question. On what basis is Sabda pramana valid? Why should one accept the Vedas as an authoritative infallible text?

Comment: @SwamiVishwananda, Jaikrishnan is exactly correct. I never claimed I am a Vedantin. More over you have completely skipped the question, please do edit or delete your answer

Comment: @Jaikrishnan Visit [What is the validity of Authoritativeness of vedas?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/14755/277)

Comment: @Pandya in the link you have given there is no proper convincing answer establishing Vedas as pramanas.

Comment: @ChakrapaniNRao Then you can wait until you find satisfactory answer. You can comment asking for clarification underneath any answer or can discuss in chat room. You may also think of starting bounty on that question with providing optional message what you're looking for. Anyway, repeating the same question would not be a good idea.

Comment: @Pandya again as I said in the comment section of the question, "What is the validity of Authoritativeness of vedas?" is only a subset of the argument. Here I am questioning the validity of the status quo opinion of vedantic schools, which would be the best question. The answer, if any present, will be in all totality, this question questions the entire final conclusion from the root. All the questions which were pointed by you, are but parts of the question, and I believe this is one of the reasons why none of the questions you pointed to has elaborate and conclusive answers.

Comment: Sir how would you convince Buddhists? As they don't accept Vedas.

Answer (score 0):

One argument I have heard in a discourse is the following: A vast number of people have believed the authority of the Vedas for a long time. If it were not the case that Vedas were followed from time immemorial then it would have been very difficult to convince so many people it is authoritative because a number of rules and restrictions (for instance, the caste system) that the Vedas proclaim would have been resisted by the vast majority. Thus unless the Vedas have been considered an authoritative source from the very beginning of Man, it would been impossible for such vast number of people to accept the Vedas. A text could have existed from the beginning of Man only if it is apoursheya. Any work that is apoursheya is automatically authoritative.

The person giving the discourse phrased it in a far better way. I don't find this argument remotely convincing.

Comment: It's a good common sense argument. The problem with this answer is any old thing such as Bible, Quran can be proved by the same reasoning. And it also holds the long held status quo as the right one. Imagine you being the first person to say Earth was round, a similar argument could be made against you. And I also suspect that this is not the traditional approach, I was looking for the traditionalist approach..

Comment: @Chakrapani N Rao. I agree with your objections. The person giving the argument was a Sanskrit Professor in my college and he is an ardent follower of the Madhva school. He attributed the argument to Madhva. However, I have been searching for over a decade to find a source for this argument and so far have been unable to find any.

Comment: Yes, I may be wrong, this **may be** one of the traditional approach

Answer (score 0):

God could be way better explained using Samkhya, because Vedanta doesnot divide Turiya into two parts but Samkhya does it.

https://asitis.com/10/26.html

Even Krishna says Kapila, progenitor of Samkhya is the most perfected being

> asvatthah sarva-vrksanam devarsinam ca naradah gandharvanam
>   citrarathah siddhanam kapilo munih
>
> Of all trees I am the holy fig tree, and amongst sages and demigods I
>   am Narada. Of the singers of the gods [Gandharvas] I am Citraratha,
>   and **among perfected beings I am the sage Kapila.**

Normally it cant be explained because Ishwara Prakṛti is the first cause of the manifest material universe—of everything except the puruṣa. Prakṛti accounts for whatever is physical, both mind and matter-cum-energy or force. Since it is the first principle (tattva) of the universe, it is called the **pradhāna, but, as it is the unconscious and unintelligent principle,** **it is also called the jaDa.**

[image]

> Samkhya is strongly dualist. Sāmkhya philosophy regards the universe
>   as consisting of **two realities, puruṣa (consciousness) and prakṛti
>   (matter)**. Jiva (a living being) is that state in which puruṣa is
>   bonded to prakṛti in some form. This fusion, state the Samkhya
>   scholars, led to the emergence of buddhi ("intellect") and ahaṅkāra
>   (ego consciousness). The universe is described by this school as one
>   created by purusa-prakṛti entities infused with various permutations
>   and combinations of variously enumerated elements, senses, feelings,
>   activity and mind.[13] During the state of imbalance, one of more
>   constituents overwhelm the others, creating a form of bondage,
>   particularly of the mind. **The end of this imbalance, bondage is called
>   liberation, or kaivalya, by the Samkhya school**

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Samkhya

Kaivalya Moksha is explained here and is permanent unlike other Salokya, Sameepya etc.,
[What is Kaivalya Moksha?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/28704/what-is-kaivalya-moksha)

This difference in explained clearly in Upanishads here:-

> Higher than the senses, stand the objects of senses. Higher than
>   objects of senses, stands mind. Higher than mind, stands intellect.
>   Higher than intellect, stands the great self. **Higher than the great
>   self, stands Avyaktam. Higher than Avyaktam, stands Purusha**. Higher
>   than this, there is nothing. He is the final goal and the highest
>   point. In all beings, dwells this Purusha, as Atman (soul), invisible,
>   concealed. He is only seen by the keenest thought, by the sublest of
>   those thinkers who see into the subtle. —Katha Upanishad 3.10-13

1) Avyaktam - Prakriti/Sagun Brahman
Sagun Brahman is explained here as Avyaktam or Prakriti, Avyaktam means inexpressible

2) Purusha- Nirgun Brahman/Aham (not to be confused with Ahamkaar)

When one identifies himself with Purusha, from there comes:

> स्वतः पूर्णः परात्माऽत्र ब्रह्मशब्देन वर्णितः | अस्मीत्यैक्य-परामर्शः
>   तेन ब्रह्म भवाम्यहम् || "Infinite by nature, the Supreme Self is
>   described here by the word Brahman (lit. ever expanding; the ultimate
>   reality); the word asmi denotes the identity of aham and Brahman.
>   Therefore, (the meaning of the expression is) "**Aham Brahmasmi/I am Brahman.**" This
>   realization is gained through true enquiry.[3]

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aham_Brahmasmi

> Samkhya is known for its theory of guṇas (qualities, innate
>   tendencies).[21] Guṇa, it states, are of three types: sattva being
>   goodness, compassion, illumination, and positivity; rajas being
>   activity, chaos, passion, and impulsivity, potentially good or bad;
>   and tamas being the quality of darkness, ignorance, destruction,
>   lethargy, negativity. All matter (prakṛti), states Samkhya, has these
>   three guṇas, but in different proportions. The interplay of these
>   guṇas defines the character of someone or something, of nature and
>   determines the progress of life

**But one can never identify himself with Prakriti/Avayktam both as per Vedanta and Samkhya as Prakriti is unconscious and Jada**

Prakriti is basically Shakti or sarvabhuteshu(prapanch etc.,)
while Purush is Shiva or bhutnaath

This is explained in Bhagwat Geeta as Kshetra(Prakriti) and Kshetragya(Purush)
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kshetrajna

**Self is Purush or Kshetragya or Nirguna Brahmana while Saguna Ishwara is Prakriti or Kshetra**

https://www.speakingtree.in/blog/gautam-buddha---does-god-exist

> Later in the evening, another person came and asked, "Does
>   God exist?". Buddha did not answer and kept silence. Then he closed
>   his eyes. On seeing this, the man also became silent and closed his
>   eyes.

God is inexpressible(Avyaktam) and hence Buddha remained silent and is manifestation of Prakriti.

But the real self Nirguna Brahman is even higher than Prakriti and is called Sat Chida Ananda

Aatmastakam - Chidananda Roopah Shivoham Shivoham

[https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FwusNKr6Pxk](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P7ymp.gif)

> Mano Budhyahankaar Chitani Naaham, Na Cha Shrotra Jihve Na Cha Ghraana
>   netre Na Cha Vyoma Bhumir Na Tejo Na Vayuh, **Chidananda Rupah Shivoham**
>   Shivoham
>
> Na Cha Praana Sanjno Na Vai Pancha Vaayuhu, Na Vaa Sapta Dhaatur Na Va
>   Pancha Koshah Na Vaak Paani Paadau Na Chopasthapaayuh, Chidaananda
>   Rupah Shivoham Shivoham
>
> Tranlsation:
>
> I am not mind, nor intellect, nor ego, nor the reflections of inner
>   self (chitta). [more] I am not the five senses.I am beyond that. I am
>   not the ether, nor the earth, nor the fire, nor the wind.I am indeed,
>   That eternal knowing and bliss, Shiva, love and pure consciousness.

[What is the source of Sat Chit Ananda mantra?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/29542/what-is-the-source-of-sat-chit-ananda-mantra/)

https://en.wikisource.org/wiki/The_Complete_Works_of_Swami_Vivekananda/Volume_3/Lectures_from_Colombo_to_Almora/Reply_to_the_Address_of_Welcome_at_Madura

> In course of time other laws had to be made. These in turn will have
>   to go, and other Smritis will come. This is one fact we have to learn
>   that the Vedas being eternal will be one and the same throughout all
>   ages, but the Smritis/Puranas will have an end.

**Smritis will have end in future and so does idol worship and superstitions**

> Ekam evadvitiyam" "He is One only without a second. Non-dual"
>   [Chandogya Upanishad 6:2:1]1
>
> "Na casya kascij janita na cadhipah." "Of Him there are neither
>   parents nor lord. That is He is self-born" [Svetasvatara Upanishad
>   6:9]2
>
> "Na tasya pratima asti" "There is no image of Him." [Svetasvatara
>   Upanishad 4:19]3

Comment: Thanks for all the great information, its really wonderful. But you have completely missed rigorous technical nature of the question and you have went about explaining the model of Sankhya which has almost nothing to do with my question which is How do Vedantis claim to establish Vedic-Theism based on Shabda pramana. So please edit or delete this answer

Comment: Vedas are Shrutis and themselves are Pramana and eternal truth unlike Puranas

Comment: That is what the question is, how can you consider Vedas to be pramana? Consider me temporarily not taking Vedas as pramana, how will you convince me?

Comment: Go and enquire with 4 Shankarcharya Matthas that know way more Hindu Dharma than you and me and ask them "why Vedas-Shrutis are superior and eternal ". Matthas were established by Adi Shankaracharya himself who protected Hinduism from Buddhism in past and reestablished Sanatan Dharma. Every Hindu is supposed to do 4char dham yatra close to 4 matthas  once in their lifetime if one call himself a real Hindu.

Answer (score 0):

Excellent question! I can give you some thought as per Vaishnava systems of Vedanta such as that of Gaudiyas (my favorite).

Let's first focus on this question: 
"elaborate enough to make the point as to how Vedas are established as Authoritative pramana"

When we buy a product, a device such as a machine or a Tv or a computer to browse the internet, etc, what we also get with this product is a document called *The User Manual* or *User Guide*. User Manual prepared by the manufacturer provides important information on how to use a product. With proper use of a device, what we learn from *The User Manual*, there is much less risk of bringing the device out-of-order or to use a device in some improper way which manufacturer did not give a device purpose to be used for. That's why we should always read and learn *The User Manual* before we start using the device. Of course we should use the device according to what we learned from the User Manual.

Now, Vedanta teaches that everything what we get in this world, namely our body, place to live or this world where we are born, etc, is like a device or a product made by a manufacturer, Lord Vishnu, given to us to use it in our lives to fulfill the purpose of human life. And Vedic scriptures are like *The User Manual* which Lord Vishnu gave to people as a revelation, it's a word of God, so that we can learn from it how to properly use our body and everything else, how to live, what to believe in, what to do in life, and everything we have to know to fulfill the purpose of human life.

Lord Krishna says in the Bhagavad-gita 15.15:

> By all the Vedas, I am to be known. Indeed, I am the compiler of Vedānta, and I am the knower of the Vedas.

Here he says that he is the compiler of Vedanta and knower of the Vedas. So he gave us Vedic knowledge and he knows how to properly explain his "product" because he says "I am the knower of the Vedas", and that's why we should learn from him. It's like learning from the *User Manual for Human Life*.

"How does Vedanta (Uttara Mimamsa) school prove their Astikya (Existence of God) using Shabda pramana?"

It can be proved with Lord Krishna's statements from the Bhagavad-gita which is Shabda pramana or "the word of God":

> O conquerer of wealth [Arjuna], there is no Truth superior to Me. Everything rests upon Me, as pearls are strung on a thread. (7.7)
>
> By all the Vedas, I am to be known. (15.15)
>
> I am the goal, the sustainer, the master, the witness, the abode, the refuge and the most dear friend. I am the creation and the annihilation, the basis of everything, the resting place and the eternal seed. (9.18)

From those verses we learn that Lord Krishna is base of everything, the goal to be attain to and known through the Vedas, the master or Lord, ie God, -- which are all the description of the Supreme God or Lord.

Comment: Pranams, Thank you for the answer. This answer would be valid if one considers Krishna and Bhagavath Gita as pramana first and then from that infer that Vedas are reliable. But if the former assumption is not made, this answer is not valid. My question how can we establish Vedas as a valid pramana from pure reason and empirical knowledge.

Comment: @Chakrapani 1. Sorry but I thought you want an answer from the standpoint of the schools of Vedanta, and I gave you quotes from the Bg because it is one of the primary scriptures of Vedanta. 2. There is no way how to establish Vedas as a valid pramana from pure reason and empirical knowledge! It requires you to believe in Vedas. That's the only way.

Comment: @Chakrapani Just like it requires you to believe in The User Manual when you buy some product and you get the manual with that product.

Comment: "There is no way how to establish Vedas as a valid pramana from pure reason and empirical knowledge! It requires you to believe in Vedas" are you sure that is the traditional opinion? Because I have heard the contrary

Comment: there is two more assumptions, the validity of the comparison is questionable. As I don't remember buying anything, this world as I was forced into existence. It's like somebody coming and putting a TV in your home without permission. And there is no one manual inside it, there are many manuals. How do you choose??

Comment: @Chakrapani Well, I'm pretty much sure about what I said above because whatever reason the tradition may tell you it still requires of you to believe in that reason, so belief cannot be excluded from the arguments which a tradition will tell you.

Comment: @Chakrapani What besides the Vedas you consider as possible options to choose from? Don't name all the religious scriptures in the world, but just those you are interested in, if here are some besides the Vedas at all.

Comment: again you are kinda making a faith argument. Consider me right now as a parama nasthika, how will you convince me?

Comment: @Chakrapani There is no way how to convince you.