# Why did Swami Vivekananda say that Dvaita, Vishistadvaita and Advaita are all correct?

Tags: advaita, vishishtadvaita, vivekananda, dvaita

Swami Vivekananda said that Advaita, Vishistadvaita and Dvaita--all these doctrines are correct.

What did He mean by saying this?

Comment: can you quote that part where he said?

Comment: @AkshayS its in His Vani o Rachana.

Comment: [Why isn't there one Absolute Reality?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/8876/277)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Because Swami Vivekananda considered them as three steps in Spiritual progress. First step is Dvaita (dualism), second step VisistAdvaita (qualified non-dualism) and third step is Advaita (non-dualism) (final state of experience).  He also said all three complement each other but do not oppose.

Swami Vivekananda says the following in [Vedanta Philosophy - Volume 1 of Complete works](https://en.wikisource.org/wiki/The_Complete_Works_of_Swami_Vivekananda/Volume_1/Lectures_And_Discourses/The_Vedanta_Philosophy).

> The Vedanta philosophy, as it is generally called at the present day,
> really comprises all the various sects that now exist in India. Thus
> there have been various interpretations, and **to my mind they have
> been progressive, beginning with the dualistic or Dvaita and ending
> with the non-dualistic or Advaita.**

Swami Vivekananda answers the following when he was asked about relationship between Advaita and Dvaita, (from [Volume 5](https://en.wikisource.org/wiki/The_Complete_Works_of_Swami_Vivekananda/Volume_5/Questions_and_Answers/I_Discussion_at_The_Graduate_Philosophical_Society_of_Harvard_University)).

> Q.—Is the Advaita antagonistic to dualism?
>
> A. —The Upanishads not being in a systematised form, it was easy for
> philosophers to take up texts when they liked to form a system. The
> Upanishads had always to be taken, else there would be no basis. Yet
> we find all the different schools of thought in the Upanishads. Our
> solution is that the Advaita is not antagonistic to the Dvaita
> (dualism). We say the latter is only one of three steps. Religion
> always takes three steps. **The first is dualism. Then man gets to a
> higher state, partial non-dualism. And at last he finds he is one with
> the universe. Therefore the three do not contradict but fulfil**.

He also says only through practice we can know which is true. He says  the following in [Volume 6](https://en.wikisource.org/wiki/The_Complete_Works_of_Swami_Vivekananda/Volume_6/Notes_Of_Class_Talks_And_Lectures/Notes_Taken_Down_In_Madras,_1892-93).

> Buddha came to whip us into practice. Be good, destroy the passions.
> Then you will know for yourself whether Dvaita or Advaita philosophy
> is true— whether **there is one or there are more than one**.

Swami Vivekananda explains his understanding in more detail in letter to Alasinga in [Volume 5](https://en.wikisource.org/wiki/The_Complete_Works_of_Swami_Vivekananda/Volume_5/Epistles_-_First_Series/XXXIX_Alasinga).

> Now I will tell you my discovery. All of religion is contained in the
> Vedanta, that is, in the three stages of the Vedanta philosophy, the
> Dvaita, Vishishtâdvaita and Advaita; **one comes after the other**. These
> are the three stages of spiritual growth in man. Each one is
> necessary. This is the essential of religion: the Vedanta, applied to
> the various ethnic customs and creeds of India, is Hinduism. The first
> stage, i.e. Dvaita, applied to the ideas of the ethnic groups of
> Europe, is Christianity; as applied to the Semitic groups,
> Mohammedanism. The Advaita, as applied in its Yoga-perception form, is
> Buddhism etc.
>
> Now by religion is meant the Vedanta; the applications
> must vary according to the different needs, surroundings, and other
> circumstances of different nations. You will find that although the
> philosophy is the same, the Shâktas, Shaivas, etc. apply it each to
> their own special cult and forms. Now, in your journal write article
> after article on these three systems, showing their harmony as one
> following after the other, and at the same time keeping off the
> ceremonial forms altogether. That is, preach the philosophy, the
> spiritual part, and let people suit it to their own forms. I wish to
> write a book on this subject, therefore I wanted the three Bhashyas;
> but only one volume of the Ramanuja (Bhashya) has reached me as yet.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/92247/discussion-on-answer-by-the-destroyer-why-did-swami-vivekananda-say-that-dvaita).

Comment: Excellent!!!!!!

Comment: "The Advaita, as applied in its Yoga-perception form, is Buddhism etc." -   Can someone explain to me what this means?

Comment: In a site where Goddess Durga can be mentioned as a Maid-Servant of Lord Vishnu, I feel ashamed to bring Sri Ramakrishna, Sri Ramana, Swami Vivekananda, Sri Krishnaprema and other saints. So I want to delete all my questions and answers  on them including this one. But deletion is not being allowed. Please do the needful.Thanks.

Comment: @Pratimaputra This is not a Hindu site but a site about Hinduism. Answers based on texts of all the sects and based on words of all the Acharyas are allowed and accepted.

Comment: @Pandya :'Answers based on texts of all the sects and based on words of all the Acharyas are allowed and accepted'--  its MISTRANSLATION and MISINTERPRETATION  OF TEXTS of the links provided.You could check yourself.