# If god is one then why there are different ending to the world according to different religion?

Tags: gods, kali-yuga

I am really confused every religion seems to claim the message of god then why they are so different?Why there are different endings.There is second coming in the Christians?Every religion seems to claim the path of god.Is there any proof or evidence of Gods message?

Comment: Hypocritical Human intellect can concoct anything and make people believe it. For example I can say Xyz is god who wants people to eat animals, start a sect. That doesn’t mean it is the truth. Similarly all these other religions are mere hypocritical stories. The truth must be sought by a true seeker and the method is as explained by the great Rishis and Munis.

Comment: Related: [Why isn't there one Absolute Reality?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/14698/277)

Answer (score 1):

Other religions are false

> या वेदबाह्याः स्मृतयो याश्च काश्च कुदृष्टयः ।
>
> सर्वास्ता निष्फलाः प्रेत्य तमोनिष्ठा हि ताः स्मृताः ॥ ९५ ॥
>
> उत्पद्यन्ते च्यवन्ते च यान्यतोऽन्यानि कानि चित् ।
>
> तान्यर्वाक्कालिकतया निष्फलान्यनृतानि च ॥ ९६ ॥
>
> Those ‘revealed texts’ that are outside the Veda, as also all the
> false theories, are useless, even when carried to perfection; as they
> have been declared to be founded on ‘darkness.’—(95)
>
> Those other (doctrines) which spring up and perish are all worthless
> and false, being of modern growth.—(96)
>
> From manusmriti ch 12

But this one could be doubtful as one  is saying from same book that a book is true. (this type of argumentation is mocked by atheists.)

How to be sure of evidence?

So rebirth can be proved

In last 50 years of research, DOPS has collected over 2500 cases of the reincarnation type([Source](https://med.virginia.edu/perceptual-studies/our-research/children-who-report-memories-of-previous-lives/))

A   [Website](https://www.reincarnationresearch.com/childrens-past-life-memories-and-the-research-of-ian-stevenson-md/)  with many recorded cases

With many books (by Jim Tucker , Ian Stevenson ),research(University of Virginia) and many claims (Shanti Devi and others) rebirth can be trusted.

If rebirth is proved then Abrahamic religions are false

> Reincarnation is refuted by all the main monotheistic religions of the
> world.[Source](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3705678/)

Reincarnation  is a central tenet of the Indian religions such as Hinduism, Buddhism, Jainism, and Sikhism.

So, any of the above religions can be true.

Here, one argument can be given: why God would wait for centuries to reveal the true way. Additionally, they all agree on the doctrine of Karma.

it is better to check scriptural ideas now.

> From Book VII - Jain Ramayana (Rāmāyaṇa)
>
> Daśānana with Śambūka and Lakṣmaṇa are in the fourth hell([source](https://www.wisdomlib.org/jainism/book/trishashti-shalaka-purusha-caritra/d/doc214126.html))
>
> Rāma had four chief queens: Maithilī, Prabhāvatī, Ratinibhā, and
> Śrīdāmā, the fourth .([Source](https://www.wisdomlib.org/jainism/book/trishashti-shalaka-purusha-caritra/d/doc214083.html))

So ,Jainism requires to mock others .A true religion won't require itself to be continued by other religion's history that  too fabricated accounts.

Same problem can be traced in Buddhism

> Dasaratha renounced the ways of evil, and reigned in righteousness. Of
> his sixteen thousand wives, the eldest and queen-consort bore him two
> sons and a daughter
>
> the elder son was named Rama-paṇḍita, or Rama the Wise, the second was
> named Prince Lakkhaṇa, or Lucky, and the daughter's name was the Lady
> Sītā   Jataka tales No. 461.DASARATHA-JĀTAKA.[Source](https://sacred-texts.com/bud/j4/j4025.htm)

If you are interested you can read Satyarth Prakash[CH 11](http://satyarthprakash.in/english/chapter-eleven/)to [CH 14](http://satyarthprakash.in/english/chapter-fourteen/)

ANOTHER PROOF (all characteristics of initial Kaliyug told in [Mahabharat](https://sacred-texts.com/hin/m03/m03189.htm) are true)

> ***Men with false reputation of learning will contract Truth*** and the old will betray the senselessness of the young, and the young will
> betray the dotage of the old. And cowards will have the reputation of
> bravery and the brave will be cheerless like cowards. And towards the
> end of the Yuga men will cease to trust one another. And full of
> avarice and folly the whole world will have but one kind of food. And
> ***sin will increase and prosper, while virtue will fade*** and cease to flourish. And Brahmanas and Kshatriyas and Vaisyas will disappear,
> leaving, O king, ***no remnants of their orders***.....
>
> Men will begin to slay one another, and become wicked and fierce and
> ***Without any respect for animal life***, then will the Yuga come to an end. And, O king, even the foremost of the regenerate ones,
> afflicted by robbers, will, like crows, fly in terror and with speed,
> and seek refuge, O perpetuator of the Kuru race, in rivers and
> mountains and inaccessible regions. And always o***ppressed by bad
> rulers with burthens of taxes, the foremost of the regenerate
> classes***...