# Are all religions correct?

Tags: philosophy

It is being said that - Yato Dharma Tato Jayah. (Wherever there is Dharma there is victory)

But all religions have won in some part of the world and established themselves there. So, that means all religions are correct ?

Comment: Similar - https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/8876/why-isnt-there-one-absolute-reality/

Comment: Similar - https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/53058/if-god-is-one-then-why-there-are-different-ending-to-the-world-according-to-diff

Answer (score 4):

As we know, Dharma has many meanings and it is a very broad word. For example, when Dharma gets with a prefix, the meaning changes to duty like PutraDharma, pitrudharma, etc.

However, coming to the point, in this context, the word 'Dharma' means 'Righteousness' and not 'Religion'.

The shloka in this question is incomplete, the complete shloka is found in the Mahabharata.

> **यतो धर्मस्ततः कृष्णो यतः कृष्णस्तो जयः।**

> "I have known all this through the grace of Vyasa endued with great
> wisdom. Thy wicked sons, however, all entangled in the meshes of
> death, do not, from ignorance, know them to be Nara and Narayana. Nor
> do they, entangled in the meshes of death, know that the hour of this
> kingdom hath arrived. Dwaipayana and Narada, and Kanwa, and the
> sinless Rama, had all prevented thy son. But he did not accept their
> words. There where righteousness is, there are glory and beauty. There
> where modesty is, there are prosperity and intelligence. **There where
> righteousness is, there is Krishna; and there where Krishna is, there
> is victory.**"

Here, Sanjaya refers to righteousness and not some religion. For better understanding, I would suggest to read the complete section once. I am providing it below.

The shloka which is asked in the question without the word 'Krishna' is also present in Mahabharata:

> त्यक्त्वाधर्मं च लोभं च मोहं चोद्यममास्थिताः। युध्यध्वमनहंकारा **यतो
> धर्मस्ततो जयः**

This happens when Yudhishthira doubts the strength of his army and thinks that their army will not win, then Arjuna says these words to Yudhishthira.

> Hear, O king, how soldiers that are few in number may vanquish the
> many that are possessed of every quality. Thou art without malice; I
> shall, therefore, tell thee means, O king. The Rishi Narada knows it,
> as also both Bhishma and Drona. Referring to this means, the Grandsire
> himself in days of old on the occasion of the battle between the Gods
> and the Asuras said unto Indra and the other celestials.--They that
> are desirous of victory do not conquer by might and energy so much as
> by truth, compassion, righteousness and energy. 1 Discriminating then
> between righteousness, and unrighteousness, and understanding what is
> meant by covetousness and having recourse to exertion fight without
> arrogance, **for victory is there where righteousness is.**--For this
> know, O king, that to us victory is certain in (this) battle.

So, from both of these cases, we can see that the word **'Dharma'** means **'Righteousness'** and not **'Religion'** in this context.

Source:

[Mahabharata- Bhishma Parva- Bhagavat Geeta Parva- Section 23](https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m06/m06023.htm)

[Mahabharata- Bhishma Parva- Bhagavat Geeta Parva- Section 21](https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m06/m06021.htm)

Comment: Yes , but what is right and what is wrong can be decided only by religious texts.

Comment: I have updated the answer. You can have a look now and if you have any query please comment and let me know :)

Comment: //Yes , but what is right and what is wrong can be decided only by religious texts// ----  Yes, but in this context, the word 'righteousness' is to be interpreted as 'Pandavas are right and Kauravas are wrong' ... Since, pandavas are righteous , victory is assured to them because where there is righteousness, there is victory.