# What is the source of the verse "yato dharmastato jayaḥ"?

Tags: translation-request, source

The emblem of the supreme court of India bears the following inscription.

> यतो धर्मस्ततो जयः (yato dharmastato jayaḥ)

What is the source of this verse? Wikipedia says it is Mahabharata. But does not provide the verse number. Please provide the verse with the verse number and the meaning in English.

Comment: Check this out...I have provided the verses in this answer. Hope this helps. https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/53102/26679

Comment: @LSSJBroly verse number?

Comment: Check out Mahabharata- Bhishma Parva- Chapter 23- Shloka 11

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`यतो धर्मस्ततो जयः (yato dharmastato jayaḥ)` is from [Mahabharata: Bhishma Parva: Chapter 21: Verse 11](https://archive.org/details/bIJP_mahabharat-vol.-3-udyog-parva-and-bhishma-parva-with-hindi-trans.-by-ramnarayan-/page/n620/mode/1up?view=theater&ui=embed&wrapper=false):

> [image]
>
> Discriminating then between righteousness, and unrighteousness, and understanding what is meant by covetousness and having recourse to exertion fight without arrogance, for **victory is there where righteousness is**. ~ [English translation source](https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m06/m06021.htm)

Answer (score 2):

This shloka in interpreted from **Bhishma Parva XXIII** verse 28.

[image]

**Edit: 1:** I found another reference of this shloka in Mahabharat Stri Parva Shloka 12 of Chapter 14. (Gita press edition)

[image]