# What is the source of the verse, which says "yataḥ kṛṣṇastato dharma"?

Tags: mahabharata, krishna, translation-request, source

I found an interesting verse in the answer provided by Sanatana darshan to the following question ([What is the source of the verse "yato dharmastato jayaḥ"?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/54780/what-is-the-source-of-the-verse-yato-dharmastato-jaya%e1%b8%a5/54783#54783)). It says "yato dharmastataḥ kṛṣṇa" (Krishna is there where Dharma is).

However, I know of a phrase, which is mentioned (without any verse number or chapter number) by Nrisinghaprasad Bhaduri in his "Katha Amritasaman" ( a discussion on Mahabharata). That phrase is just the opposite. It says "yataḥ kṛṣṇastato dharma" (Dharma is there where Krishna is).

I am wondering whether he misquoted it or if there is really another verse in Mahabharata, which says just the opposite. If the verse is from Mahabharata, please provide the full verse along with the verse number and English translation.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

***'yataḥ kṛṣṇastato dharma'*** is also mentioned in Mahabharata [here.](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/mahabharata-sanskrit/d/doc1036372.html)

> उक्तवानस्मि दुर्बुद्धिं मन्दं दुर्योधनं पुरा ।
> **यतः कृष्णस्ततो धर्मो** यतो धर्मस्ततो जयः ॥

> uktavānasmi durbuddhiṃ mandaṃ duryodhanaṃ purā |
> **yataḥ kṛṣṇastato dharmo** yato dharmastato jayaḥ || [*Anuśāsana parva*:153:39]

Answer (score 7):

> राजन् सर्वमयो ह्येष तमोरागविवर्जितः ⁠।
> यतः कृष्णस्ततो धर्मो यतो धर्मस्ततो जयः ⁠।⁠।⁠ ३५ ⁠।⁠।

> राजन्! ये श्रीहरि सर्वस्वरूप और तम एवं रागसे रहित हैं। जहाँ श्रीकृष्ण हैं, वहाँ धर्म है और जहाँ धर्म है, वहीं विजय है ⁠।⁠।⁠ ३५ ⁠।⁠।

> O king! He is full of truth. He is devoid of darkness and passion. Where there is Krishna, dharma exists there. Where there is dharma, victory exists there. ।⁠। 35 ।⁠।

Verse number - Mahabharata 6.66.35 (Bhishma Parva [Bhishma-vadha Parva], Chapter 66, Verse 35)

Source - Mahabharat, Gita Press, Gorakhpur, Hindi Translation (Sn & Hn).

> “I said this to the wicked and evil-minded Duryodhana. ‘Wherever
> Krishna exists, dharma is there. Wherever dharma exists, victory is
> there.”

Anushasana Parva, Bhishma-Svargarohana Parva, Chapter 1834 ( 153 ), BORI Critical edition.

Comment: Thank you for finding this new verse. A blog is not an authentic source. You have to cite the original source. I did it for the first verse on behalf of you.

Answer (score 6):

Following the lead of @SanatanDarshan, I found this verse in Gita press Hindi Mahabharat. There it is in Anushashana Parva, Chapter 167, verse 41

> रक्ष्याश्च ते पाण्डवेया भवान् येषां परायणम् ⁠।
> उक्तवानस्मि दुर्बुद्धिं मन्दं दुर्योधनं तदा ।⁠।⁠ ४० ⁠।⁠।

> **यतः कृष्णस्ततो धर्मो** यतो धर्मस्ततो जयः।
> वासुदेवेन तीर्थेन पुत्र संशाम्य पाण्डवैः ⁠।⁠।⁠ ४१ ⁠।⁠।

> The sons of Pandu should ever be protected by thee. Thou art, indeed, already their sole refuge. Formerly, I spoke to the foolish Duryodhana of wicked understanding that **thither is Righteousness where Krishna is**, and that there is victory where Righteousness is. I further counselled him that relying on Vasudeva as his refuge, he should make peace with the Pandavas. [Mahabharata 13.167.40-41]

The translation is from Mahabharata of Krishnadvaipayana Vyasa by Kisari Mohan Ganguly.